# Gulp Watch performs all tasks again instead of just those that were changed

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-4

I have problems with Gulp Watch when it only has to process the files that have been modified

When I start, Gulp performs the tasks correctly, but when I make a change Gulp watch performs all the tasks again instead of just those that were changed. I do not know what the problem could be, could you help me?

```
// Watch Task: watch SCSS and JS files for changes
// If any change, run scss and js tasks simultaneously

function watchTask() {
    watch([files.htmlPath, files.scssPath, files.mincssPath, files.cssPath, files.minjsPath, files.jsPath, files.imgPath], 
        parallel(htmlTask, siteTask, series(scssTask, cleanTask, concatCSS), series(jsminTask, jsTask), imgTask));    
}

// Export the default Gulp task so it can be run
// Runs the scss and js tasks simultaneously
// then runs cacheBust, then watch task

exports.default = series(
    parallel(htmlTask, siteTask, series(scssTask, cleanTask, concatCSS), series(jsminTask, jsTask), imgTask), 
    cacheBustTask,
    watchTask
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you should create separate watch functions and run them in parallel.

Some thing like that:

```
exports.watch = gulp.parallel(watch_html, watch_scss,...);

function watch_html() {
    return gulp.watch(files.htmlPath, htmlTask);
}

function watch_scss(){
    return gulp.watch(files.scssPath, series(scssTask, cleanTask, concatCSS));
}
```